# Increase verbosity of running rsync process?

Tags: rsync

I'm running 'rsync -a -i /foo /bar'. Every now and then I would like to know what exactly rsync is doing at the moment without having the -v output all the time. Is it possible to increase the verbosity of running processes e.g. by sending a kill signal?

Comment: Type ps afux|grep rsync Get the process ID (second field), then strace -e trace=file -p PID And type Ctrl-C when you want to quit.

Comment: Good answers in this http://askubuntu.com/questions/323775/monitor-watch-running-rsync-process question

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would redirect the output in a file and then `tail -f` to see the output when desired:

```
rsync -a /foo /bar >/tmp/rsync.log 2>&1
```

when needed:

```
tail -f /tmp/rsync.log
```

Comment: That's what I do right now ;-) But I was hoping there is something like the 'kill -USR1' for 'dd'

Answer (score 52):

I use `rsync -v --stats --progress`

Answer (score 14):

In addition of -i, you can use --progress for more verbosity in sending data.
for example:

```
rsync -ai --progress .....
```

If need more and more the better way is logging it as @Marc M said above.

Answer (score 3):

The `rsync` documentation does not describe such behaviour, nor is there a (proper or de-facto) standard signal to send to a process in order to modify its verbosity.

However thanks to the incremental nature of `rsync` you should be able to abort a running `rsync` with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and re-run it with '-v' and not lose much time as a consequence.

Comment: Thanks pablomme. Ctrl+C and re-run is not an option for me because I'm syncing to a slow davfs mount.