# Monitor/Watch running rsync process

Tags: rsync

I have an rsync job that has been added to a crontab and when it's running, I can only check that there's a rsync PID and confirm with htop that it's eating up n amount of CPU and RAM.

What I'd like to do is to monitor what files are actually being rsync'ed in realtime...when I want to. FYI I haven't passed any verbose option to the command nor have I added some logging. I really just want to check what's being rsync'ed on demand.

Any idea how I could achieve that?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can do (in POSIX shells, including `bash`):

```
strace -e open,openat $(ps -o lwp= -LC rsync | sed 's/^/-p/')
```

Or in `zsh`:

```
strace -e open,openat -p${^$(ps -o lwp= -LC rsync)}
```

Or in `fish`

```
strace -e open,openat -p(ps -o lwp= -LC rsync)
```

Or in `rc`/`es`:

```
strace -e open,openat -p`{ps -o lwp= -LC rsync}
```

To see what it's doing, or

```
lsof -ad3-999 -c rsync
```

to see what files it currently has opened.

Comment: At the time or writing (linux 4.15.0) you probably want `strace -e openat` instead

Comment: Thanks @piro, I've added it.

Comment: You could [ask for `/proc`](https://askubuntu.com/a/1351113/295207) without resorting to `strace` or `lsof`!

Answer (score 3):

The most simple solution would be redirecting the output of rsync to a logfile.

```
rsync -avz /something /somwhere >> ~/rsynclog
```

Comment: the goal of the question is to have a status of the current rsyincing, without having any verbose/logging on [Probably to be more flexible, and to avoid always logging (and ending up with tons of lines of rarely needed rsync logs)]

Answer (score 1):

Another way you could is if you know the rough directory you'll be syncing (ie, we'll use the directory 'movies' for example) you can use a combination of lsof and grep:

> lsof | grep rsync | grep movies

lsof will list your open files, pipes the output to grep to find any opened by rsync, pipes that output to grep to find the directory/file which is open.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways

**With screen:**
Attach screen session to your cron job:

screen rsync --progress  src dst

this will allow you to re attach to the rsync jobb anytime you want to check what files its currently processing (just be sure to be the same user as the one that launched the rsync job)
with

```
screen -x
```

**With logging**
add logging to your rsync job:

```
rsync --log-file=/tmp/rsync-status.txt  src dst
```

then follow the log in real time with:

```
 tail -f /tmp/rsync-status.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

As [Király István](https://askubuntu.com/users/225338/kir%C3%A1ly-istv%C3%A1n) suggested, I am running

`rsync -ravz /Users/jkirby/Music/iTunes/* .`

which gives output like

```
Jeffs-MBP-2:2016-08-15 jkirby$ rsync -ravz /Users/jkirby/Music/iTunes/* .
building file list ... done
Temp File 1.tmp
Temp File.tmp
```

From that output I can see what directory is being copied.

In the case where `rsync` is copying a lot of large files slowly, I monitor that directory using `watch` like so. This way I can see the temp file that `rsync` creates and I can see the size growing on the file currently being copied.

`watch -n1 "~/Music/iTunes"`

Answer (score 0):

## Monitor running process under GNU/Linux

### Monitor `rsync` transfert on *both ends*

By running Linux kernel, you could query `/proc` pseudo filesystem. There is no need to resort to `strace` or `lsof`, (could be useful on small configuration where this tools could even not be installed).

```
ps -C rsync fw
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
 8645 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/bin/rsync --daemon --no-detach
13763 ?        S      0:01  \_ /usr/bin/rsync --daemon --no-detach
13764 ?        S      1:30      \_ /usr/bin/rsync --daemon --no-detach

ps -C rsync fwo pid,lstart,stat,cmd
  PID                  STARTED STAT CMD
 8645 Sat Jul 10 14:34:12 2021 Ss   /usr/bin/rsync --daemon --no-detach
13763 Sat Jul 10 15:51:23 2021 S     \_ /usr/bin/rsync --daemon --no-detach
13764 Sat Jul 10 15:51:23 2021 S         \_ /usr/bin/rsync --daemon --no-detach
```

The 1st process is the *daemon*, looking for *start time* show two process started by remote rsync.

So, looking for the last one:

```
mapfile -t allrsyncpid < <(ps -C rsync fho pid)
rsyncpid=$((${allrsyncpid[@]: -1}))
```

Then with this **`$rsyncpid`** variable:

```
ls -l /proc/$rsyncpid/fd
total 0
lr-x------ 1 root root 64 jui 10 15:51 0 -> /dev/null
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 jui 10 15:51 1 -> socket:[106279330]
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 jui 10 15:51 2 -> socket:[106279330]
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 jui 10 15:51 3 -> socket:[106279331]
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 jui 10 15:51 4 -> /path/to/some/file.IxOWxh
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 jui 10 15:51 5 -> socket:[106323027]
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 jui 10 15:51 6 -> socket:[106320690]
```

Then

```
ls -l $(readlink /proc/$rsyncpid/fd/4)
-rw------- 1 root root 41024 Jun 10 15:59 /path/to/other/file.ZIjEDk
```

If you repeat this, you could see wich file are growing and how.

```
while [ -d /proc/$rsyncpid ] ;do
    ls -l $(readlink /proc/$rsyncpid/fd/4)
    read -t .5 foo && break
done
-rw------- 1 root root 0 Jul 10 16:16 /path/to/some/file.nMM3Lz
-rw------- 1 root root 0 Jul 10 16:16 /path/to/other/file.H2b61i
-rw------- 1 root root 0 Jul 10 16:16 /path/to/some/bigfile.B0Xgg7
-rw------- 1 root root 2097152 Jul 10 16:16 /path/to/some/bigfile.B0Xgg7
-rw------- 1 root root 42359296 Jul 10 16:16 /path/to/some/bigfile.B0Xgg7
```

Until you press <kbd>return</kbd> or the end of rsync process.

Of course, as you are watching for `/proc` entries, created and deleted very quickly by another process, there are some chance `ls` is executed too late after `readlink`. So this kind of message is not harmful:

```
ls: cannot access '/path/to/some/file.fKSZss': No such file or directory
```

### Sender side vs reciever side.

Previous `ls` command will let you see file grown, because file doesn't exist before.

On sender side. As files are *read*, there are another nice `/proc` subdir: `/proc/PID/fdinfo`. Entries in this dir hold information about current pointer:

```
ps -C rsync w
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
3762 pts/13   D+     3:18 rsync -ax /path/to/source/. rsync://rsyncserv/target

ls -l /proc/13762/fd
total 0
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 jui 10 16:27 0 -> /dev/pts/13
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 jui 10 16:27 1 -> /dev/pts/13
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 jui 10 16:27 2 -> /dev/pts/13
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 jui 10 16:27 3 -> socket:[106321578]
lr-x------ 1 root root 64 jui 10 16:27 4 -> /path/to/some/file
```

Then

```
cat /proc/13762/fdinfo/4
pos:        2883584
flags:      0100000
mnt_id:     131
```

Where `pos` is current position in file, `flag` represent how this file is accessed (0100000 mean LARGEFILE, see [`asm-generic/fcntl.h`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/include/uapi/asm-generic/fcntl.h) in your source tree ;-) and `mnt_id` indicate which filesystem file is located on.

So:

```
rsyncpid=$(($(ps -C rsync ho pid)))
while [ -d /proc/$rsyncpid ] ;do
    read -r _ pos </proc/$rsyncpid/fdinfo/4
    crtfile=$(readlink /proc/$rsyncpid/fd/4)
    filesize=$(stat -c %s "$crtfile")
    printf "Crtfile: %s (%d), crtpos: (%d)\n" "$crtfile" "$filesize" "$pos"
    read -t .5 foo && break
done
Crtfile: /path/to/some/bigfile.iso (17985276), crtpos: (2097152)
Crtfile: /path/to/some/bigfile.iso (17985276), crtpos: (6553600)
Crtfile: /path/to/some/bigfile.iso (17985276), crtpos: (11272192)
Crtfile: /path/to/some/bigfile.iso (17985276), crtpos: (15990784)
```

Same as before: until you press <kbd>return</kbd> or the end of rsync process.

### Server vs client side.

In this sample. `rsync` command was initiated for an external system, to **send/write** datas to the server.

In case `rsync` command is used to **read/recieve** datas from server, the method stay sames but on the *other side*:

- To determine *rsync `PID`*

  - server side:

    ```
    mapfile -t allrsyncpid < <(ps -C rsync fho pid)
    rsyncpid=$((${allrsyncpid[@]: -1}))
    ```
  - client side:

    ```
    rsyncpid=$(($(ps -C rsync ho pid)))
    ```
- To follow in file progress

  - sender side:

    ```
     while [ -d /proc/$rsyncpid ] ;do
         read -r _ pos </proc/$rsyncpid/fdinfo/4
         crtfile=$(readlink /proc/$rsyncpid/fd/4)
         filesize=$(stat -c %s "$crtfile")
         printf "Crtfile: %s (%d), crtpos: (%d)\n" "$crtfile" "$filesize" "$pos"
         read -t .5 foo && break
     done
    ```
  - reciever side:

    ```
     while [ -d /proc/$rsyncpid ] ;do
         ls -l $(readlink /proc/$rsyncpid/fd/4)
         read -t .5 foo && break
     done
    ```

### And for other tools...

This work for any tool accessing files. You could watch for `tar`, `sha1sum`, `gzip`, `cat`, `dd`, ....